# Can't deploy using serverless framework from Windows 10

Tags: serverless-framework

Attempt to deploy via serverless framework using Windows 10 fails:

> C:\Users\xxxxxx>sls deploy --verbose  Serverless: Packaging
>   service...  Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
>
> Error --------------------------------------------------
>
> EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir
>   'C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\ElevatedDiagnostics'  For debugging
>   logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
>
> Your Environment Information -----------------------------  OS: win32 
>   Node Version: 6.11.2  Serverless Version: 1.19.0
>
> Tried again with command prompt under elevated privileges:
>
> EBUSY: resource busy or locked, scandir
>   'C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\InputPersonalization\TextHarvester\WaitList.dat'

I assumed there was a permissions issue at first so I retried with the command prompt at full admin mode but just ran into the the second error.  My research suggested an issue with windows search so I turned it off (and also all background apps). Trying again (and again) I just ran into more similar issues and am unable to deploy anything. Anyone had similar issues and found a way around them?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out finally, so in case anyone else encounters this issue here is a summary.  There seem to be 2 issues:

1. Don't create functions in your root folder.  Create a specific folder for your serverless function i.e. not in C:\Users\nnnnnn> but within your regular document storage.  In Windows 10 it works nicely if you use a OneDrive folder, with the benefit that your function(s) are also then replicated to other dev machines that you might use (and are automatically backed up offsite).
2. More importantly, the serverless framework seems to have an issue if you attempt to deploy to a region other than the default region set in your aws CLI configuration.  I've no idea why this should be since the credentials I use with the AWS CLI are authorised for all regions.  I also have no idea why the issue should result in serverless attempting to access a whole series of windows files for which it has no authority but nevertheless...

In my case, I primarily use region ap-southeast-2.  By default, SLS CREATE generates a serverless.yml using a default US region.  If this is left as-is, there is then a mismatch between the deployment region and your AWS CLI region.  Not good.  To avoid the minor pain of having to specify a deployment region in the SLS deploy command, just update the deployment region in the serverless.yml file to match the CLI region.

Now works a treat...